# HTML5 audio tag onplaying even is triggered before audio play in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html5-audio

I have write a code for highlight text according to audio. In this the logic is when audio start playing we fire a highlight function. which highlight each word for given no of time.

And it is working fine for window PC and Desktop. But In android highlight function trigger before audio start that is why audio and highlight is not synchronized.

Below is the code.

```
function highlight(start,totalWords,aid) {  

            var wtime =   data[start]/defaultPlayback;
            $("#W"+start).css("color",'yellow'); 
            setTimeout(function (){    
            $("#W"+start).css("color",'');     
            start++;
            if (start <= totalWords) {highlight(start,totalWords,aid);}
            else{return false;}       
            }, wtime);    


        }

<audio  preload='auto' controls id='a2' onplaying="highlight(10,18,'bookread4');"  onended="completed('a3')" >

  <source src="http://arbordalepublishing.com/eBooks2/Animalogy/Animalogy p7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



<span id="W10" class="calibre2">Chick </span>
<span id="W11" class="calibre2">is </span>
<span id="W12" class="calibre2">to </span>
<span id="W13" class="calibre2">feathery,</span>
<span id="W14" class="calibre2">as </span>
<span id="W15" class="calibre2">bear </span>
<span id="W16" class="calibre2">is </span>
<span id="W17" class="calibre2">to </span>
<span id="W18" class="calibre2">furry.</span>
```

Comment: you are not defining data as seen in first line of function highlight ... also function completed is missing ... please edit your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of driving the text with a timer/counter, which you will have no guarantee will synchronize, you should use the `currentTime` property of the audio element. This will force correct time independent on start.

The property returns current absolute time in fractional seconds. Use this time to check time range for the word to be highlighted.

For example (just arbitrary times here as the original data is not available):

```
var words = [
    {
        id: "W10",            // or use reference to element
        start: 0,             // time in seconds
        end: 0.2,
        highlighted: false    // to reduce DOM updates
    },
    {
        id: "W11",
        start: 0.22,
        end: 0.4,
        highlighted: false
    },
    ... etc. ...
];
```

Then in highlight:

```
function highlight() {

    var time = a2.currentTime,
        i = 0, word;

    for(; word = words[i++];) {
        if (time >= word.start && time <= word.end)
          if (!word.highlighted) {
            word.highlighted = true; // to reduce the need to update DOM
            // ... set CSS for highlighted here...
          }
        }
        else if (word.highlighted) {
            // ... set CSS for not highlighted here...
            word.highlighted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Live demo

Try pausing it during play and you will see text is still able to sync when continued.

```js
// NOTE: these are not 100% synchronized - they are just for example
var words = [
    {id: "W10", start: 0, end: 0.7, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W11", start: 0.76, end: 1.1, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W12", start: 1.2, end: 1.3, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W13", start: 1.4, end: 2.1, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W14", start: 2.1, end: 2.3, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W15", start: 2.3, end: 2.7, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W16", start: 2.7, end: 3.0, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W17", start: 3.0, end: 3.2, highlighted: false},
    {id: "W18", start: 3.2, end: 3.4, highlighted: false}],
  audio = document.getElementById("a2");

audio.onplaying = highlight;

function highlight() {
  var time = a2.currentTime, i = 0, word;

    for(; word = words[i++];) {
        if (time >= word.start && time < word.end) {
          if (!word.highlighted) {
            word.highlighted = true; // to reduce the need to update DOM
            document.getElementById(word.id).style.color = "orange";
          }
        }
        else if (word.highlighted) {
            document.getElementById(word.id).style.color = "black";
            word.highlighted = false;
        }
    }

  // you should listen to end event and stop the loop using that, here, for simplicity:
  if (!audio.paused) setTimeout(highlight, 17);
  //else alert("done");
}
```

```css
body {font: bold 16px sans-serif}
```

```html
<audio preload='auto' controls id='a2'>
  <source src="http://arbordalepublishing.com/eBooks2/Animalogy/Animalogy p7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<br>
<span id="W10">Chick </span>
<span id="W11">is </span>
<span id="W12">to </span>
<span id="W13">feathery,</span>
<span id="W14">as </span>
<span id="W15">bear </span>
<span id="W16">is </span>
<span id="W17">to </span>
<span id="W18">furry.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Ken Fyrstenberg, This is working very fine. I will check it on android. I think it will work now.

Comment: Dear Ken Fyrstenberg, I have played your demo code in window -7 Desktop. Its working perfect. But when i play in android tab i saw very strange result :-

1. In chrome => It play but only highlight first word and i think its due to not getting current time of audio in it. 

2. In Mozila => Your demo audio is not playing by clicking it

3. In opera => In opera your demo is not visible.

Comment: @KrishnaNandan the actual result depends on the support in the browser unfortunately. For example, Opera Mini does not support Audio element. Also check if the chain of event callbacks is correct over-all (my demo is only focusing on synchronizing the words to time). There can be prefixed event names and so forth. Also take a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#search=audio (click on the little red asterix next to the browser name for details). See if you can log the different steps and possible errors in a console (or output them in the browser window). This should help locate the error.

Comment: Dear Ken Fyrstenberg, You are right. I have  to check whether browser support or not. But can i know one thing sir, You have used infinite loop to check current time, in between checking time can i perform another jquery operation? As I know java Script is single threading. So how it operate 2-3 tasks at the same time.

Comment: @KrishnaNandan the setTimeout makes it asynchronous (in the demo, about one frame, you can lower the rate using 33ms instead - or use requestAnimationFrame as a better choice). As each setTimeout will create a timer event, the browser can do other tasks in the mean time until the event expire - then this function is called again, and eventually added back to the event queue. In simple words, there shouldn't be any problems doing other tasks. It will only run once, wait etc. Everything is still single-threaded but there are time-slots available to do other things. Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Ken, you really explain in such a way so that anyone even a fresher can understand. Thanks Ken Fyrstenberg.Now i become your fan. Can you please advice me how can i read these types of things in jquery and java script. Because i only know basic things that is why i faces some problem sometimes.

Comment: @KrishnaNandan thanks Krishna, glad I could help. A good starting point could be f.ex. [it-ebooks.info](http://it-ebooks.info/book/1361/). I haven't read these, but you will likely find one that suits need and area.

Comment: @ Ken Fyrstenberg Thanks sir