# function for a video HTML5

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

How could make him appearing alert on the 5th second of a video HTML5 excluding the buffer loading time? I tried with currentTime but I can not display anything ...

```
<video id="video1"><source src="url" type="video/mp4" /></video>
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: provide proper **src**.

Comment: what do you mean you cannot display anything? show us what you have tried.

Comment: I want to run a javascript function which is a counter ( I put alert here for convenience) and want to appear on the 5th second video.
But not counting the time it takes to reproduce the video so setTimeout, setInterval ... not worth ...

Comment: you can do a setinterval that runs frequently and then in each iteration check the currentTime of the html5video and if it has surpassed you second quantity then you can type alert. but thats a tad expensive in cpu and it would be much cleaner to have some kind of an event for this.

Comment: you could set me an example please ...

Comment: no you need to do this yourself.

Comment: This should be able to help you out - it's for audio but video and audio share the same base element so it will work for video as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811139/html5-audio-tag-onplaying-even-is-triggered-before-audio-play-in-android/28866943#28866943

Comment: can also look at 'timing events', here: http://www.sitepoint.com/essential-audio-and-video-events-for-html5/. looks like thats your event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) or [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is a **bad** idea because user can, for example, pause the video, or if the video is buffering, ... so it's not a accurate manner to do what you are looking for.

Instead of that, you can use the [`timeupdate`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp) event to verify the [`currentTime`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) of your video, like this :

```
$(function(){

    var video = $('#video1')[0], current_time = 0, alert_showed = false;

    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
        current_time = Math.floor(video.currentTime);
        if(current_time == 5 && !alert_showed){
            alert_showed = true;
            alert('text here : ' + current_time);
        }
    })

})
```

You can see a working example of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akmozo/Lhhzkv72/).

Hope that can help.